# Swift 5 - MacOS App - Interacting with other applications

Tags: swift, macos, bots

I'm trying to make a small bot that would require to get colors of specific locations on the screen, to click/double click & use letters from keyboard.

That bot would simply help me save time to launch my games since I'm lazy.
For example, I launch the bot (with a small window with a button that says "go" or something like that, and other buttons where I can select the game i want), it double clicks on the correct icon's position, and once it detects a precise pixel combination, it would click on the correct positions & input my login/password and launch the game.

My question is:
Is it possible to do this using Xcode Swift5 MacOs app ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Please read these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is there anything you don't get in my question ? I'm trying to give details of my bot's actions so you better understand what I'm looking for.
As for the code example, I have a MacOs application with MVC structured, but I doubt this would be any help. I'm stuck at the point where I don't know if it is possible for an application to use some mouse/keyboard event on other applications. Which means I don't have any useful code to share.

Comment: If that is your position then SO really isn't the place for your question. SO has specific rules for closing questions that begin with, "Is it possible...?" "How do I...?" "Show me how...?" It's for questions about problems with code. Have you tried the Apple Developer boards?

Comment: I get what you mean, but I doubt apple dev board would be very helpful.
I saw that my request is more "script" oriented.
I have no idea if I can do some scripting using swift or/and macos app with Xcode.
Since you don't seem to want to help me, I'll continue my researchs by myself & post my findings on this thread..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I chose to switch on windows and used .net with visual studio 2019. It was incredibly easy.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

But it's not the easiest thing to do and needs a lot of setups and time.

I suppose that you haven't worked with Swift or Xcode yet so I would not recommend to learn both for such a simple task.

Instead take a look at the application "Script Editor" which is already installed on your Mac. It lets you write code in Applescript (which is a lot more readable and "English-like", rather than code) and gives you exactly the instruments you need.

Here you have a simple code to doubleclick:

```
tell application "System Events"
  click at {10, 10}
  delay 0.1
  click at {10, 10}
end tell
```

Here one to press a key

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.5
    keystroke space using command down
end tell
```

Btw `keystroke` can be used to type entire words and sentences, too.

And with a quick google search here you also have the code to get the hex color at a given x,y:

```
do shell script "screencapture -R{x},{y},1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && \
                 xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | \
                 sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"
```

Comment: I worked with xcode/swift for over 4 years ^^
I really thought I would find another way than getting a screenshot to check a pixel, but even in .net I had to use that trick.
Thank you for the answer tho !